# Trying to run a simple program to test a template function, but it always results in no match for function found error

Tags: c++, function, templates

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template < class T, class V, class F, class R >
T Fct (T x, V y, F z, F p)
{
  return x + (y + z) * p;
}

int main ()
{
  int n = 1, p = 2;
  float q = 2.3, r = 1.5;
  double y = 3, z = 6;
  unsigned m = 2;
  const int h = 3;
  cout << Fct (n, q, y, z);
  cout << Fct (q, n, n, p);
  cout << Fct (r, y, n, r);
  cout << Fct (y, z, m, p);
  cout << Fct (y, z, h, n);
  cout << Fct (y, h, q, r);
  cout << Fct (r, y, m, h);
  cout << Fct (h, m, n, p);
  return 1;
}
```

When I run it, it displays an error on each `cout` operation that says:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Fct(double&, double&, const int&, int&)'

Comment: The `R` type can't be deduced.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th arguments need to have the same type but they have different types. What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: Maybe `p` (4th argument) is intended as an `R`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the question is to determine which cout statements can be executed or not...I just removed the "class R" , most of them worked except the ones where the last two are (int, float); (unsigned int, int); (const int, int). The (int, float) one I understood why.. but the other two why didn't they work? is unsigned or const int different than int?

Comment: @max66 what does that mean? why would having an extra parameter in the template affect the program? what if I just didn't want to use it in the current code?

Comment: Because the compiler has to set a type for `R`; but a type of `R` can't be deduced from the arguments of the functions so the only way is explicit it. But `R` is the last template parameter, so you have to explicit all of them, also the one that can be deduced, so a possible call is `Fct<float, int, int, void>(q, n, n, p);`

Comment: @user12294261 Was your question answered by my answer or do I need to clarify anything?

Answer (score 1):

The template parameter `R` isn't used in the argument list of the function so it can't be deduced which is why the compiler complains. All template parameters must be specified or deduced. It's likely that you should use `R` for the last argument:

```
template<class T, class V, class F, class R> 
T Fct (T x, V y, F z, R p) {
    return x + (y + z) * p;
}
```

Note that specifying `T` as the return type will prevent the normal promotion that happens when you mix different types. An alternative would be to let the promotion do its work by specifying the return type as `auto`:

```
template<class T, class V, class F, class R> 
auto Fct (T x, V y, F z, R p) {
    return x + (y + z) * p;
}
```

C++11 version:

```
template<class T, class V, class F, class R> 
auto Fct (T x, V y, F z, R p) -> decltype(x + (y + z) * p) {
    return x + (y + z) * p;
}
```

If you remove `R` and make it

```
template<class T, class V, class F> 
T Fct (T x, V y, F z, F p) {
    return x + (y + z) * p;
}
```

...you will not be able to compile the program if you pass different types to `z` and `p`, like `unsigned int&` and `int&`. If you however pass an `int` and `const int`, `F` will be deduced to `int` (not a reference) and the compilation will succeed.